# Using the man command in Unix, I want to list file names with file size etc.

Tags: file, unix, ls, manpage

By using the man command  I want to list the names of the files I have already created with extra information such as filesize, date of modification etc.

I know I have to use the man command possibly something like:

```
man ls | documents
```

But this would not seem to work. If anyone would know how to do this that would be great? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `man` command lets you read the documentation for other unix commands. piping the documentation for `ls` to anything else seems extremely unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: `I want to list the names of the files I have already created with extra information such as filesize, date of modification etc` `man` is manual for commands. perhaps you are looking for `ls -l > document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `man` to read the contents of the manual, not list files.

Use `ls` to list your files.

Use `ls -l` to list files with extra information.

Use `ls -la` to list all files (including hidden) with extra information.